# Given a standard regression output table in a publication, how do you compute p-values?

Tags: r, regression

If I'm looking at a paper that reports regression coefficients and the standard errors in parenthesis, I know that I can compute a t-statistic by dividing the coefficient by its SE.  However, how can I then compute an exact p-value from this if I know the number of observations?  I'm guessing this is the procedure:

```
t <- coefficient / se
df <- n - k (where n is the number of observations reported, and k is the coefficients estimated including intercept)
(1 - pt(q = abs(t), df = df))*2
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is border-line off-topic but since it requires some statistical knowledge to answer.

pt(abs(t), df, lower.tail = FALSE) * 2

would be preferred as it avoids an unnecessary subtraction.

Comment: Got it.  And I'm correct in saying that the df computation is just the total number of observation minus the total count of variables reported in the summary table + the intercept?

Comment: Yes, you lose one for each parameter and the intercept counts as a parameter.